# python RuntimeError: Can not call init more than once

Tags: python

While running the test cases for my python NER code, I am facing the below Run time error:

```
tests/unit/test_app.py:8: in <module>
    from app import *
app.py:31: in <module>
    setup_json_logs(app)
src/tools/log.py:27: in setup_json_logs
    json_logging.init(framework_name="flask")
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/json_logging/__init__.py:111: in init
    raise RuntimeError("Can not call init more than once")
E   RuntimeError: Can not call init more than once
=====================================================
```

code: log.py

```
import logging
import json_logging
import sys
import os

#### Disable Flask request logs #### 
flask_request_logger = logging.getLogger('flask-request-logger')
flask_request_logger.disabled = True

def get_logger(name="extraction-and-matching-logger"):
    level = logging.INFO

    if (os.getenv("DEBUG")):
        level = logging.DEBUG

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
   
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
  
    return logger

def setup_json_logs(app):
    json_logging.ENABLE_JSON_LOGGING = True
    json_logging.init(framework_name="flask"
    json_logging.init_request_instrument(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are calling
json_logging.init
twice. I know the second line is different but it may still not want to do two similar initialisations. Is it possible for you to only call one of these, do you still get the error?

Comment: ```tests/unit/test_app.py:8: in <module>
    from app import *
app.py:31: in <module>
    setup_json_logs(app)
src/tools/log.py:28: in setup_json_logs
    json_logging.init_request_instrument(app)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/json_logging/__init__.py:156: in init_request_instrument
    raise RuntimeError("please init the logging first, call init(framework_name) first")
E   RuntimeError: please init the logging first, call init(framework_name) first```

Comment: I have commented the 2nd line now i got this error.